# making changes to svg element on the fly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I'm new to react, here i have svg element which is not in my code as you can see code i have provided, but it is in console, i want to change those 'height: 569px;width: 800px;' to height: 100%;width: 100%; my problem is, that does not have className and neither and id, so how can i change those values ? the other one which is above it i have changed that using that id.

that svg element have just 'name'

```js
const _zoomConfig = () => {
    const z = d3Select(`#graph-id-graph-wrapper`)
      .call(d3Zoom() as any)
      .on('wheel.zoom', null)
      .on('dblclick.zoom', null)
      .on('mousedown.zoom', null)
      .on('touchstart.zoom', null)
      .on('touchmove.zoom', null)
      .on('touchend.zoom', null);
  };
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    _zoomConfig();
  });
```

```css
#graph-id-graph-wrapper {
  /* margin-left: -100%; */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

console:

[image]

i dont know if this is reacts way, i have tried this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const k = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('svg')).map(
      (elem) => elem,
    );

   
    k.map((elem) => {
      if (elem.getAttribute('name') === 'svg-container-graph-id') {
        elem.setAttribute('height', '100%');
        elem.setAttribute('width', '100%');
      }
    });
  });
```

it doesnt affect it:
[image]

English is not my mother language so there could be mistakes.

Comment: Any idea is appreciated !

Comment: What you've done seems about right. If it's not working please add a [mcve] to the question ideally as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) Maybe the style is overriding the attribute i.e. you should remove the style attribute when you set the height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the inline style properties instead:

```
elem.style.width = '100%';
elem.style.height = '100%';
```

But I guess the graphs dimensions i.e. aspect ratio is also needed for a proper display. So adding a `viewBox` attribute might be a good idea:

```
elem.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 569 800');
```

Ideally you'll set these properties on creation/initialization.
See also: [A simple way to make D3.js charts responsive](https://medium.com/@louisemoxy/a-simple-way-to-make-d3-js-charts-svgs-responsive-7afb04bc2e4b)